# "Updating Damageline Data in Tuple: OPL CPLEX Code for Time-Dependent Modifications"

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am working on the code for 5 hours. The data that I have is

tuple LineParameter {

int Line;

string Damageline;

}

LineParameter linedata [Line] = [

<1,  "ND">,

<2,  "ND">,

<3,  "D">,

<4,  "ND">,

<5,  "ND">,

<6,  "D">,

<7,  "ND">,

<8,  "D">,

<9,  "D">,

If I want to update the value of the string Damageline from "D" to "ND," the following updates should occur: at the 2nd hour, the Damageline data of lines 3 and 6 get updated from "D" to "ND". Similarly, at the 4th hour, the Damageline data of lines 8 and 9 get updated from "D" to "ND". Write a code in OPL CPLEX to update the data in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scripting:

```
range Line=1..9;

tuple LineParameter {

int Line;

string Damageline;

}

LineParameter linedata [Line] = [

<1, "ND">,

<2, "ND">,

<3, "D">,

<4, "ND">,

<5, "ND">,

<6, "D">,

<7, "ND">,

<8, "D">,

<9, "D">];

execute
{
  writeln(linedata[8]);
  linedata[8].Damageline="ND";
  writeln(linedata[8]);
}
```

gives

```
<8 "D">
 <8 "ND">
```

And if you use a time index you can keep all values:

```
range Line=1..9;

tuple LineParameter {

int Line;

string Damageline;

}

LineParameter linedata [Line] = [

<1, "ND">,

<2, "ND">,

<3, "D">,

<4, "ND">,

<5, "ND">,

<6, "D">,

<7, "ND">,

<8, "D">,

<9, "D">];

LineParameter linedatatime [h in 1..4][l in Line]=linedata[l];

range r2=2..4;
execute
{
  // Change at hour 2
  for (t in r2)
  {
  linedatatime[t][3].Damageline="ND";
  linedatatime[t][6].Damageline="ND";
 }  
 // change at hour 4
 linedatatime[4][8].Damageline="ND";
 
  writeln(linedatatime[1][3]);
  writeln(linedatatime[2][3]);
  
  writeln(linedatatime[1][8]);
  writeln(linedatatime[4][8]);
  
}
```

which gives

```
<3 "D">
 <3 "ND">
 <8 "D">
 <8 "ND">
```

Comment: I have to change the string damageline with time.

Comment: With this time-varying data for damaged lines, I want to define a set that varies with time. The code that I am trying to find time varying set of damaged lines is

Comment: {int} DamagedLines = {};                                                                                                                                   
execute {                                        // set of lines with switches
for (var l in Line) {
for (var s in Slot){
if (linedata[l].Damageline == "D") {            // Set of damaged lines
DamagedLines.add(linedata[l].Line);
}
}
}

Comment: But with this code, I am not getting a time-varying set of damaged lines. I am getting the same element for all time slots. Suggest me code in opl CPLEX to define a time-varying set.

Comment: LineParameter linedatatime [h in 1..4][l in Line] provides several results when h (time) moves from 1 to 4